# Basic db-mysql setup error

Tags: node.js

I just started using node.js for my project and tried making a connection to MySQL and inserting basic values. But I keep getting the following error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Unable to load shared library /Users/****/nodeJS/node_modules/db-mysql/build/Release/mysql_bindings.node
    at Object..node (module.js:472:11)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/****/nodeJS/node_modules/db-mysql/db-mysql.js:18:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
```

I did as was instructed, I specified the MYSQL_CONFIG environment variable:

```
$ export MYSQL_CONFIG=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe it's too late and I hope you solved this problem on your own, but it might be useful for other people experiencing the same issue.

What I did to solve it is to set the following variable:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=<your absolute path to mysql lib folder>
```

in my case it is:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql-5.5.25-osx10.6-x86_64/lib/
```

Tested on MacOS Lion 10.7.4